# Click/DoubleClick to open a Userform on Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I was just creating a template on Word which uses content controls and I have a userform to help auto fill the data which is activated via a command key. You know how on excel VBA you can click a cell to make it refresh or open up a userform, or perform a series of tasks. On Word, can you double or single click a Content Control per say and have a userform pop up?

I think it would be pretty neat to be able to do that, open for any ideas that I should try out.

Comment: You can add an ActiveX control from the Developer tab. ActiveX controls have events.

Comment: Word content controls do not have "click" events. The Word application has a Window_BeforeDoubleClick event that you might be able to use... But as it stands your question is "too broad" for the site. Please take a moment to read the guidelines on asking questions in the [help].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike Content Controls, ActiveX controls have Click and DoubleClick events. You can add an ActiveX control (e.g., a button or a label) and use its Click event to do whatever you want:

[image: ActiveX controls]

And then simply, use something like this:

```
Private Sub lblTest_Click()
    MsgBox "You clicked on a label."
End Sub

Private Sub btnTest_Click()
    MsgBox "You clicked on a button."
End Sub
```

Result:

[image: Label clicked]

Hope that helps.